# How to check if a branch was rebased?

Tags: git

`git reflog` says `pull: Fast-forward` but is there an easy way to see which commits were added?

Say I pull some branch where someone else rebased that branch and now I want to see what the difference is to the state it was in before I pulled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
git fetch
```

to fetch all remote changes without merging/rebasing, so then you will be able to check git log of changes and check commit hashes before rebasing/merging.